# formatting javascript number to years and month

Tags: javascript

I get an integer such as 20 from it, I need to calculate how many months and years are in it, in 20 for example 1 year and 8 months
how do i do this in JS?

```
   case (props.term === 12):
        setYears(1)
        break;
     case (props.term >12):
        ...
     break;
     default:
        break;
  }
```

Is there another way?

Comment: Yes; make use of Math.floor, and the modulo operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var years = Math.floor(term/12);
var months = term % 12;
```

Answer (score -1):

First i would divide the month through 12 (a year) to get the amont of years:

Math.floor(20 / 12) = 1

Then I would take the input modulo the amount of month in a year so you get the dangeling months.

20 % 12 = 8

(Sorry for my English)